# PFXImportCertStore- issue - cryptoapi

Tags: security, cryptography, digital-signature, cryptoapi, pfx

I imported a third party CA issued PFX certificate using `PFXImportCertStore`. Upon successful importing, the `PCERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` is set to the following values by **default** by the same call, `PFXImportCertStore`

[image]

1. Why is the `dwKeySpec` recognised as `AT_KEYEXCHANGE`key type rather than `AT_SIGNATURE`?
2. Why is the `pwszProvName` set to Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0?
3. The certificate in the first place was issued ONLY for Digital signing. But the key usage field indicates that the certificate can be used for Digital Signature, Non-Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment (f0). Enhanced key usage indicates, Client Authentication and Secure Email? Has the CA has issued the certificate correctly? The front of the certificate shows the following message(screen shot below) which makes me to suspect that this certificate was not issued for digital singing? Am i thinking correctly or not?

[image]

4.Because of these issue, i am unable to sign data using `CryptSignMessage`. The internal call fails to acquire context to the private key for signing. Any suggestions on how i can get around this issue?
I am able to sign with a selfsigned PFX cert which i generated. Do you think that i could export the private key in to new container and set it property to `AT_SIGNATURE` and the csp provider Type to `PROV_RSA_AES`, as i require SHA256.

I am working with XP sp3.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer 1: The key is automatically classified as `AT_KEYEXCHANGE` because, its usage is also to encrypt session key etc. ie Though my application's main purpose is to digitally sign data, the CA has defined the key usage policy to include encipher, which forces CryptoAPI to map the key type to `AT_KEYEXCHANGE`.

Answer 2: I **ASSUME** that it is a default csp in this machine, so...? Any better explanation, please

Answer 3: From many replies from guys in Crypto Google group, [`AT_KEYEXCHANGE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121740/decrypt-data-using-an-rsa-public-key/3151105#3151105) key can also be used to sign data, provided your certificate's key usage allows you to do digital signing. It seems to be common practice for third party CA's to issue certificates that can be used for multiple purposes. So the third party CA has issued the certificate correctly.

Answer 4: I managed to sign data using `CryptSignMessage` with the same third party issued certificate. I changed the `dwProvType` in `PCERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` to `PROV_RSA_AES` and passed in NULL for `pwsProvName`. This change is performed by using `CertGetCertificateContextProperty` first to get the properties and then using `CertSetCertificateContextProperty`  to set the properties of your choice. This fixed the signing issue. Now i am able to sign with [SHA256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191312/windows-cryptoapi-cryptsignhash-with-calg-sha-256-and-private-key-from-my-keysto/4191721#4191721)/RSA1024, `AT_EXCHANGE` key.